# Large Number Power Method

Tags: java, biginteger

I can't figure out why, but when the power function is used, it adds a (what seems to be random) integer into the middle of the answer.  I can't figure out why, can any of you see anything unusual?  Thanks

```
//multiplication method
    public IntValue Multiply(IntValue multiplier) {
        StringBuilder product = new StringBuilder();

        int pos = 0;

        for (int i = multiplier.getValue().length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int currentPosition = pos++;
            int carry = 0;
            int multiplierDigit = Character.getNumericValue(multiplier.getValue().charAt(i));

            for (int j = value.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                int multiplicandDigit = Character.getNumericValue(value.charAt(j));

                int tempProduct = currentPosition < product.length()
                        ? Character.getNumericValue(product.charAt(currentPosition)) : 0;
                int currentProduct = (multiplicandDigit * multiplierDigit) + carry + tempProduct;

                if (currentProduct > 9) {
                    carry = currentProduct / 10;
                    currentProduct = currentProduct % 10;
                }

                if (currentPosition < product.length()) {
                    product.setCharAt(currentPosition, Character.forDigit(currentProduct, 10));
                } else {
                    product.append(currentProduct);
                }

                ++currentPosition;
            }

            if (carry > 0) {
                if (currentPosition < product.length()) {
                    product.setCharAt(currentPosition, Character.forDigit(carry, 10));
                } else {
                    product.append(carry);
                }
            }
        }
        return new IntValue(product.reverse().toString());
    }



//number1 and number2 are IntValues.
//power method
    public IntValue Power(long n) {
        IntValue result = new IntValue("1");

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result = result.Multiply(this);
        }

        return result;
    }

System.out.println("Result = "+number1.Power(Long.parseLong(number2.toString())));
```

Comment: what does it return?

Comment: what is your input and return value?

Comment: What's `IntValue` ?

Comment: Show the Multiply method

Comment: @Matthew if inputs are both 5, it outputs 38125 instead of the desired 3125.

Comment: @FallAndLearn both should be IntValues

Comment: Please refactor your code and don't begin method names with capital letters

Comment: @cricket_007 added it to original post

Comment: Why don't you use `BigInteger` class?

Comment: If `long n == (long)Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1`, then the for loop will not end. `product.append(carry);` is wrong. Carry should be reset after adding (missing else?).

Comment: @JoopEggen not this case I believe.

Comment: @xenteros sorry, I did not really have time/gusto to read Multiply minutely, so I take it you are right.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Please provide all information necessary to reproduce the bug.

Comment: @sixtytrees if you put `[mcve]` will change into following int the comment: [mcve] - it's what really is all information necessary... :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
BigInteger number1 = new BigInteger("5");
System.out.println("Result = " + number1.pow(5).toString());
```

It's how we do it in `java`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library for working with powers in Java, namely Math.pow (for small numbers) and BigInteger pow (for arbitrary large numbers). Note that BigInteger power cannot compute fractional powers.

There are iterative DIY algorithms for fractional powers as well, for example

```
BigInteger sqrt(BigInteger n) {
  BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE;
  BigInteger b = new BigInteger(n.shiftRight(5).add(new BigInteger("8")).toString());
  while(b.compareTo(a) >= 0) {
    BigInteger mid = new BigInteger(a.add(b).shiftRight(1).toString());
    if(mid.multiply(mid).compareTo(n) > 0) b = mid.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    else a = mid.add(BigInteger.ONE);
  }
  return a.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
}
```

Comment: Why `x = new BigInteger(<expression>.toString());` instead of simply `x = <expression>;`? It seems to me that directly assigning the expression should give the same result without the detour of converting to and from a string.